# Magento 2 run native product csv import programtically

Tags: magento2, import

I have been searching for a way of achieving this but so far no luck. I have also looked through the core and found where it is called (`vendor\magento\module-import-export\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Start.php`) but can't work out where to define the CSV file to import.

I know I need to pass data to it like so:

```
Array
(
    [form_key] => 123456789xyz
    [entity] => catalog_product
    [behavior] => append
    [validation_strategy] => validation-stop-on-errors
    [allowed_error_count] => 10
    [_import_field_separator] => ,
    [_import_multiple_value_separator] => ,
    [import_images_file_dir] => 
)
```

Any one have any hints as to how I can run the native CSV import via code?

Thanks

Comment: I followed previous steps, but it didnt work. When I try to import product throught a csv file in backoffice, the check data is correct and the import too.
But, when I try to use the same file in my custom module, the check data function (validateSource) gives me error. I think I don't upload csv file correctly. I put it in personnal folder, then I copy it in /var/importexport/ rename as catalog_product.csv. The function importSource seems to work but no product is imported, and the file isn't copy in /var/import_history/. I'm lost. Can you help me ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143140)

Comment: If it’s any help I also use magmi, which has a new project running for m2. Works great for me. Give it a google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to inject an instance of `\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Adapter\CsvFactory` into your constructor
2. Using the `CsvFactory`, you need to create an instance of the CSV Model:

   `$csvModel = $this->csvFactory->create(['destination' => 'path/to/your/file.csv']);`
3. Using the CSV Model, write out your data:

   `$csvModel->writeRow(['your' => 'data']);`
4. Inject an instance of `\Magento\ImportExport\Model\ImportFactory` into your constructor
5. Using the `ImportFactory`, you need to instantiate the Import Model:

   `$importModel = $this->importModelFactory->create();`
6. Set any data you need to pass to the import model:

   `$importModel->setData(['your' => 'data']);`
7. Get an instance of the CSV source model:

   `$sourceModel = ImportAdapter::findAdapterFor(
       'path/to/your/file.csv',
       $this->filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::ROOT),
       $importModel->getData('_import_field_separator')
   );`
8. Validate your import:

   `$isValid = $importModel->validateSource($sourceModel);`
9. Handle the validation results:

   `if ($importModel->getProcessedRowsCount() === 0 || !$isValid || $importModel->getErrorAggregator()->getErrorsCount()) {
       // Display or log the error
       return;
   }`
10. Run the import:

    `$importModel->importSource();`

There's a lot more involved in the error handling, but this should at least get you started.

Comment: This was an absolute lifesaver. I'm so glad I found this. Thanks!!

Comment: What happened with the variable $csvModel? It is not used after step 3.

Comment: Getting Error during import "Entity not found"